# How do I use the output of a command as a variable?

Tags: python

Example.

```
import random
list = [1,2,3,4]
randint(list)
```

How do I take the output of the randint of the list and store it in a variable?
Like say out of the variable list it picks 3 how would I store it in variable X?

Comment: You mean `X = randint(list)`? (Also, did you mean `random.choice` rather than `randint`?

Comment: Exactly the same way you took the output of `[1,2,3,4]` and stored it in the `list` variable.

Comment: Python is not a Bourne Shell: `randint` does not produce any output but rather returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct function, `choice` from the `random` package (which is actually pseudorandom.)

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4] # Don't use `list` for a variable name.
>>> x = random.choice(l) # This is how you assign something to a variable.
>>> x  # This now returns the random value, echoed to output on the next line.
4
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called methods, not "commands". And the "output" is called return value.

```
x = any_method()
```

That's how you assign the return value of any method to a variable.

Comment: You didn't try this this, did you?

Comment: Why try something so obvious? Of course, I assume randint() is defined.

Comment: So obvious? `randint` does not accept a list as a parameter. Your code will give you a `TypeError`.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't ask whether his code would raise a TypeError. He asked *How do I use the output of a command as a variable?*, and this is the answer. But I'll change it anyway.